# How to Copy file from Azure Blob Storage Container to Cosmos Mongo DB Collections Dynamically using Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

We have 11 JSON files in our azure blob storage container in a folder called jsonfiles, Let's assume the file names as (a.json, b.json, c.json, d.json, e.json, f.json, g.json, h.json, i.json, j.json, k.json).

Similarly, we have 11 Cosmo Mongo DB Collection, assume the collection name as below [ a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, I, j, k].

I need to copy/upload (a.json file to 'a' collection), (b.json to 'b' collection), (c.json to 'c' collection), (d.json to 'd' collection), (e.json to 'e' collection), (f.json to 'f' collection), (g.json to 'g' collection), (h.json to 'h' collection), (i.json to 'i' collection), (j.json to 'j' collection), (k.json to 'k') collection.

I need to Achieve the above requirement through Azure Function App. If Someone is well and good with Azure Function, Please Explain in detailed how to achieve this.

Detailed Explanation is Much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

- to download the blob, you will need a `blob service client`,`container client`and a `blobclient`  . Then we can use `downloadtofile` function to download the file.
- the `downloadtofile` function will take a file location as input and will write data from the blob to a file with the same name is blob.
- There must exist a file with same name is blob.
- Similarly, now you would need a `MongodbClient` to connect to database and then we can read file which are downloaded and add them in documents which are Json objects and then use `insertOne` as     to upload the documents with our Json file to azure cosmos db mongo db.
- Here I am downloading three files and uploading them to azure

complete code:

```
// Dependencies

const { BlobServiceClient } = require("@azure/storage-blob");
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const  fs = require('fs');
const { ObjectID } = require("bson");

  

const  container_name = "test";
const  connblob = "<Connection String of Storage Account>";

  
  

module.exports = async  function (context, req) {

/// Hepls in connecting to Database
const  client = new  MongoClient("< Connectiom String of azure cosmosdb mongodb>");

  
// connecting to blob storage
var  blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connblob);

// refence of container

var  container_client = blob_service_client.getContainerClient(container_name);

  
  
// Reference of perticular blobs

var  blob_client1 = container_client.getBlobClient("a.json");

// download the blob

await  blob_client1.downloadToFile("./blobs/a.json");

  

var  blob_client2 = container_client.getBlobClient("b.json");

await  blob_client2.downloadToFile("./blobs/b.json");

  
  

var  blob_client3 = container_client.getBlobClient("c.json");

await  blob_client3.downloadToFile("./blobs/c.json");

  
// connection to databse
await  client.connect();

// creating the database

const  databse = client.db("test");

// creating collenctions

const  collection1 = databse.collection("a");

const  collection2 = databse.collection("b");

const  collection3 = databse.collection("c");

  
// Reading files

const  f1 = fs.readFileSync('./blobs/a.json', 'utf-8')

const  f2 = fs.readFileSync('./blobs/b.json', 'utf-8')

const  f3 = fs.readFileSync('./blobs/c.json', 'utf-8')

  
  // creating documents

var  t1 = {

_id:ObjectID("123456789012")

}

  

var  t2 = {

_id:ObjectID("212345678909")

}

  

var  t3 = {

_id:ObjectID("312345678901")

}

  // adding files to documents

t1["file"] = f1;

t2["file"] = f2;

t3["file"] = f3;

  // adding documents to mongodb

collection1.insertOne(t1);

collection2.insertOne(t2);

collection3.insertOne(t3);

  
  

context.res = {

// status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */

body:  "responseMessage"

};

  
  

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm new to the Function App. And could you please explain from the beginning, which Language do I need to select while creating Azure Function App and which Functions I have to take. Kindly mention on which language you have written the code. As per my understanding in your code you are creating the collection through the code. I will create the mongodb collections through terraform code. I need to upload the json files from Blob storage to Mongo DB Collections. If you can provide me solution to achieve this through terraform is also fine. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: Here I have used C# language, but azure function supports java, python, JavaScript and others. Now as far as I know Terraform can only procure resources ie. create the azure cosmosdb but it can't have any logic built in

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Java Script I can be able to understand a little. Can you help me with the code from the beginning, how you are creating the function App and how you are selecting Functions with points and screenshots. I want to copy the a.json file to existing a collection. Which I will create via terraform. Likewise, I need copy dynamically files to individual collections. Help me with the Java Script that will help. 

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have used JavaScript I accidently said c# in the previous comment sorry for that. The above code will work for existing collection . The above function is a Httptrigger means that it will act as an API I created this function using vs code . refer this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-vs-code-node)  on it how to create azure function using vs code